# Including loops in step definitions (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

I have a cucumber feature file which has a set of scenario outline. For each of the examples in the scenario outline, there is a corresponding step definition. But the issue is each example has a different xpath which needs to be iterated for a fixed number of times.
I am not being able to place a loop in the Java step definition file for the specific number of steps that need to be executed for a fixed number of times.
Thanks in advance for any help

I tried to put the loop before the step definition methods so that I could call the methods in the loop but kept getting an error of unexpected token

Following is the set of scenario steps that are defined:
`

- When I click on  filter icon
- And I enter the
- And I select specific
- And I enter again
- And I click on Filter button
- Then Grid should be filtered accordingly
- And I click on Clear Filters button
- And I click on Collapse All button
  `

My query is which step's definition should the loop be placed, since these are the repetitive steps for over 8 times.

Here is the code snippet of step definitions:

```
    @When("I click on {} filter icon")
public void filterIcon(String columnHeader) {
  // determine row
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid']//table[@role='grid']/thead[@role='rowgroup']/tr[@role='row']/th[2]//span")).click();
    }

@And("I enter the {}")
public void enterTextOne(String textOne) {
    //some name one
    Actions act1 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement val1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html//form[@title='Show items with value that:']//input[@title='Value']"));
    act1.moveToElement(val1).click(val1).sendKeys(textOne).perform();
}

@And("I select specific {}")
public void selectSpecificLogic(String logic) {
    //and or or
    WebDriverWait pause = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(3000));
    WebElement filterLogic = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html//form[@title='Show items with value that:']/div[1]/span[2]//span[@class='k-input']"));
    filterLogic.click();
    WebElement logic1 = pause.until(
            ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath(
                            "/html//form[@title='Show items with value that:']/div[1]/span[2]//span[@class='k-input']"))));
    Actions act3 = new Actions(driver);
    act3.moveToElement(logic1).click(logic1).perform();
}

@And("I enter again{}")
public void enterTextTwo(String textTwo) {
    //enter the second param here
    Actions act2 = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement val2 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[7]/form/div[1]/input[2]"));
    act2.moveToElement(val2).click(val2).sendKeys(textTwo).perform();
}

@And("I click on Filter button")
public void filterButton() {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[@class='k-animation-container']/form[@title='Show items with value that:']//button[@type='submit']")).click();
}

@Then("Grid should be filtered accordingly")
public void verifyRow() throws InterruptedException {
    //verifying row with data
    //and this
    WebDriverWait find = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10000));
    WebElement gridData = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='grid']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a"));
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    WebElement gridData1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='grid']/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a"));
    WebElement grid = find.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(gridData1));
    grid.click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    String cellData = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/span[1]")).getText();
    if (cellData != null) {
        System.out.println("grid is filtered");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Grid not filtered");
    }

}

@And("I click on Clear Filters button")
public void clearFiltersGrid() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid']//ent-grid-buttons[@class='ng-isolate-scope']/ul[@class='ent-buttons-list']//a[.='Clear filters']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(7000);
}

@And("I click on Collapse All button")
public void collapseGridRow() throws InterruptedException {
    //collapsing the rows expanded in earlier grid filter
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='grid']//ent-grid-buttons[@class='ng-isolate-scope']/ul[@class='ent-buttons-list']//a[@class='collapse-all-btn']")).click();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unexpected token sounds like you have syntax problem in the loop. Please paste the code example.

Answer (score 0):

If you write your scenario at a higher level of abstraction you can avoid some of the problems you are facing.

Generally when filtering you want to have some things that should be shown and some things that should not. You can write you filter test as something like

```
  Background:
    Given I am logged in as an admin
    Given there are some thing with foo enabled and foo disabled
    And I am viewing all the things

  Scenario: View all
    Then I should see all the foo enabled and foo disabled things

  Scenario: Filter by Foo
    When I filter things to show foo enabled
    Then I should see only the foo enabled things
    And I should not see the foo disabled things

  Scenario: Filter by No Foo
    When I filter things to show foo disabled
    Then I should see only the foo disabled things
    And I should not see the foo enabled things
```

Now your steps are working in larger chunks and are describing WHAT you are doing rather than HOW you are doing it.

You can make your step implementations simpler by making your step definitions call helper methods rather than have them contain all the code. The examples below are in Ruby, but you should be able to translate

```
Given "there are some thing with foo enabled and foo disabled" do
  @foo_enabled_things, @foo_disabled_things =
    create_foo_enabled_and_disabled_things
end
```

So here we are delegating the work of creating things to a helper method create_foo_enabled_and_disabled_things which returns two arrays which we assign to globals

Now the only difficulty is checking that the filter works. This is where you would loop on the things stored in the globals to check for their presence in the view. Somewhere in code called by a Then you would have

```
  @foo.enabled_things.each do
    ...
  end

  ...
```

Again I would suggest using helper methods so that the details of HOW you check something are

1. Low down your code stack
2. In a place where they can be re-used

Hopefully the above will give you some ideas to tidy your code and make things simpler. Good luck.